# The empty sequence is the identity element of the free monoid constructed on a set X

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $X$ be a set. Let $w=(x_i)_{1\leq i\leq m}$ and $w'=(x'_j)_{1\leq j\leq n}$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. The composition of $w$ and $w'$, denoted by $ww'$, is the family $(y_k)_{1\leq k\leq m+n}$ defined by

\begin{equation}
y_k=
\begin{cases}
x_k  & 1\leq k\leq m; \\
x'_{k-m} & m+1\leq k\leq m+n.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Let $w=(x_i)_{1\leq i\leq m}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to show that $ew=w$, where $e=(u_i)_{1\leq i\leq 0}$ is the empty sequence. Applying the above definition, $ew$ is the sequence $(y_k)_{1\leq k\leq m+0}$ defined by

\begin{equation}
y_k=
\begin{cases}
u_k  & 1\leq k\leq 0; \\
x_{k-m} & 1\leq k\leq m.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

But the expression $x_{k-m}$ makes no sense for $1\leq k\leq m$. What I am doing wrong? Am I applying  the definition incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you copy and paste your formula and replace $m$ by $0$, you get
\begin{equation}
y_k=
\begin{cases}
x_k  & 1\leq k\leq 0; \\
x'_{k} & 1\leq k\leq n.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
which gives you $ew = w$ as required.